# "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment" when running java project on another computer

Tags: java, jvm, windows-nt

I created a Java project in Netbeans that runs without issue on my computer (both in Netbeans and from running the jar file), but when I try to run the project on another computer I get the following error message:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000062478337, pid=2860, tid=0x0000000000000e84
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x68337]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

I've searched for similar issues but I can't seem to find anything that matches my error, so I'm not sure what to do. I can post the full error log if need be. If no one can figure it out, can someone at least point me in the right direction (is it a memory issue, do I need to update Java, etc)?

Comment: Run [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) on the computer that is giving that error. Also, why did you tag this question with windows-nt?

Comment: Are you using JNI methods? Are you using a library that does?

Comment: ElliottFrisch I tagged Windows NT because that's what the error log said the operating system was. 11684 I'm not sure. How would I check that?

Comment: @KoryMitchell [Which Windows operating system am I running?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13443)

Comment: Do you have full crash report (hs_err_pid.log)?

Comment: @apangin Yes. I copied and pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/ebRCyazE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `hs_err_pid.log` the crash has happened inside the native method `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext` which apparently belongs to MSSQL JDBC driver.

The most interesting part of crash dump is the line
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\sqljdbc_auth.dll`

Obviously, `sqljdbc_auth.dll` does not belong to JRE. Looks like this file was copied manually to JRE directory. This is wrong, and most likely the reason of the crash. You have to install MSSQL JDBC driver correctly and set `-Djava.library.path` JVM argument to point to the directory with driver native libraries.

Comment: This worked! The reason I had that dll file in there was because I was having a different error and that was a solution I found somewhere else, but I didn't think it would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue today in Intellij. I resolved it by pointing to new JRE version.