# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment::When Eclipse IDE interfacing with Arduino

Tags: java, eclipse, arduino, rxtx

I'm facing trouble with Eclipse IDE interfacing with Arduino. I've done all the procedures necessary for communicating between Arduino and Eclipse IDE (like installing Rxtx.jar and build path and then copy serial.dll and parallel.dll files in the Eclipse workspace folder...)

I've also checked Arduino COM port configuration in both Arduino IDE and in Eclipse code.

But still I'm getting this kind of message in the Eclipse console.

---

```
    WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
    Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
    native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Started
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180003990, pid=7556, tid=4696
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (9.0+11) (build 9.0.1+11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (9.0.1+11, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x3990]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Educational\Study\Softwares\JAVA\Eclipse EE Oxygen for Web Devlopers\workspace\RxTxDemo\hs_err_pid7556.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

---

My Eclipse IDE Java code is as follows:
(my Arduino port is COM5 and using windows 10 x64 bit.)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
        /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
            "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                        "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM5", // Windows
    };
    /**
    * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
    * converting the bytes into characters 
    * making the displayed results codepage independent
    */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
                // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
                // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
               // System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
  }
```

---

And my simple Arduino code is as follows:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("Hello world");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Kindly give suggestions to fix this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right DLLs for 64-Bit Java? http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download#x64_Binaries

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion...from your suggested link I've downloaded rxtx.jar file and DLLs and replace it in workspace....

Now I'm not getting that warning message for RXTX mismatch..that good thing....but still the rest of entire error message is as it is...!!

Comment: @PURVILVAGHELA the question is still open problem because the answer you accepted does not explain what is the reason for this Error. plz don't accept non-complete answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment" when running java project on another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638312/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-when-running-j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with Java 9 and when I changed back to Java 8 it works. 
another solution, use http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/ it works for me...

Comment: I experience the same problem with jSerialComm with OpenJDK 11

Comment: you can report a bug in https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/issues
hope they will find a solution for you

Comment: @alex_z
you may want to look on this: https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/issues/165